# Vue - Component data loaded from state undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following route in `router/index.js`:

```
routes: [
    {
        path: '/painel',
        component: Panel,
        meta: {
            auth: true
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: '/mensagem/:userId',
                name: 'panel.message',
                component: Message
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my Message component:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="head">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="image" :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + contact.avatar + ')' }"></div>
                <div class="infos">
                    <div class="name">{{ contact.name }}</div>
                    <div class="company">{{ contact.company }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import router from '../../router';
    import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';

    export default {
        name: 'Message',
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(['getContacts']),
            contact() {
                return this.getContacts.find(obj => {
                    return obj.id == router.currentRoute.params.userId;
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The `getContacts` getter return all the contacts from state:

```
export const getContacts = (state) => state.contacts;
```

When the component is called I have the following erros on console:

```
1. [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined"
2. TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar' of undefined
3. Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
4. Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

The problem is visible: When the component is loaded, contact data is not yet computed.

I only get the error when accessing the `/message/5` URL directly. When it is called through some `<router-link>` I do not have this error.

I do not know if setting the user by url is the best alternative. Is it the best alternative?

Any idea how I can run the application without this error? I'm a little perfectionist :)

Answer (score 0):

One simple/silly way to avoid error is to use :if block and render only when it has contact, If it doesnt has contact , render some message to user as loading

```html
<div class="infos" :if="contact">
                    <div class="name">{{ contact.name }}</div>
                    <div class="company">{{ contact.company }}</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I came up with this solution, but I would like to see if there is another alterative. Because I would have to check inside the `conversation` method too.

Comment: I do not know if setting the user by url is the best alternative. Is it the best alternative?

Comment: @sridhar.. it should be `<div class="infos" v-if="contact">`

Comment: @CaioKawasaki, try `contact() {
                return this.getContacts.find(obj => {
                    return obj.id == router.currentRoute.params.userId;
                }) || {};
            }` or `|| {'default value'}`